What caused pex lines to become wavy?
I have a newly built home but in the past week we have noticed our water pressure seems much lower. I have looked for leaks and can’t find anything. We are on county water and they are having no issues. The one thing I have noticed is that the main supply line of hot water that runs through the house is now wavy. It was straight but now has noticeable waves in the line. Any thoughts on what may have caused this? Could this be the cause of our pressure issue?

"No issues" doesn't translate to "no fluctuations in pressure due to additional load". You should monitor actual service pressure. Wiggly tubing doesn't sound related.

I'd suggest checking to see if you have a filter on your incoming water supply that may be clogged.  Also, is the pressure low everywhere, or just in parts of your house?

pex expands ~2" per 100' per 10°F temperature change.
The wavy-ness was caused by improper installation and not allowing for expansion.
That specifically is not the cause of your pressure issue.
If the installer was not knowledgeable enough to know how to properly run pex, sort of doesn't surprise me you would have other [pressure] problems.  Sign of the times I guess.
https://abc11.com/chatham-county-forever-home-dream-nightmare-code-violations/13321024/
